# Law of equivalence

Tags: physical-chemistry

100g mixture of nitrates two metals a and b is heated to  constant weight containing corresponding 50g oxides of the metals
{i.e METAL NITRATES(100g) --->OXIDES(50g) +(some nitrogen oxide gases) } . 
The equivalent weight of a and b are 103 and 31 respectively .What is the percent composition of a and b in the mixture?

In this question book has given that

equivalent weight of nitrate of a= equivalent weight of a + equivalent weight of nitrate ion

And similarly, 
equivalent weight of oxide of a= equivalent weight of a + equivalent weight of oxide

How to find EQUIVALENT WEIGHTS of nitrate and oxide.Can you tell me how should i calculate it or where am i going wrong?Or can you just solve this question?

[image]

Comment: How can the weight of pure metals decrease to 50 gram upon heating? Recheck your problem. Also show your attempt at the problem.

Comment: This part is problematic "100 gram mixture of two metals a and b is heated to constant weight of 50 gram containing corresponding oxides of the metals." Weight of two pure metals a and b cannot $decrease$. Recheck the wordings of the problem.

Comment: Questions are supposed to be improved and asked to be reopened,  instead of posting a new question. That is against the site policy.

Comment: 100g of metals A and B or 100g of their nitrates ? Be equation/equivalent weight you may mean molar (equivalent )mass.

Comment: Yes, it is most likely nitrates but the student must realize that there is a mistake in the wordings.

Comment: The problem has been created by a rather old teacher who has not yet accepted the mole concept. He prefers using the old theory of equivalent, which was in use in the 19th century, and cause a lot of confusions when dealing with redox equations. I would guess A is probably lead Pb, with an equivalent 103.6, and B is probably copper Cu with an equivalent weight is 31.7. But what is worse : Guest 2020 is not able to calculate the weight of the nitrate ion, even if he knows that it is 14 + 3x16. This shows that he does not know what is an atomic and a molecular mass.

Comment: Sadly, this is equivalents & normality is still taught in Indian schools I think he is more confused by the fact that formula weight of nitrate is the same as its molecular weight and why oxide's formula weight is divided by 2.

Comment: I have checked it .This is the problem and made corrections accordingly. If someone knows the correct answer or could correct me where i have written wrong or where i am getting wrong then they could rather than !!COMMENTING!!. And if you know the answer then give it and tell me why the molecular weight is same as equivalent weight??

Comment: If you spent little  of time by a quick search, you would save yourself the time spent by writing your both questions ( first closed ) : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalent_weight

A part of the site policy is not answering some questions even if the answer is well known, but commenting or closing them. Your question needed additionally a clarification. If what you wanted was quick answer for a trivial or homework-like question, post rather on Quora, they answer such questions.

Comment: Note that you have already solved on the photo what you have asked for. The rest is just solving 2 linear equations for 2 variables ( Search for it if needed ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally your problem reads correctly! Do you recall how equivalent weights are calculated for redox species and anions? What is the charge on NO$_3^-$ ? It is -1, so equivalent weight is "molecular weight"/ absolute value charge. = Anything divided by 1 stays the same.

Coming to the oxide, O$^{2-}$, the charge is -2. So equivalent weight is 16/2=8.

Keep in mind that equivalent weights are highly dependent on the reaction to reaction. Don't apply these rules without understanding the nature of the reaction. Hope it is clear now.

As an exercise, calculate the equivalent weight of KMnO$_4$, when it reduces to Mn$^{2+}$ in acidic medium. This time, you have to check how many electrons are involved.

Comment: Ok now i understand where i was wrong thanku very much. And i think the answer of the exercise should be (158/5).

Comment: Yes, this is correct.